# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Error while processing SVF

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I'm using Autodesk Forge Viewer 7.* to open DWF and DWFX files.  Most all 3d models load successfully - one model in particular throws an error

in the console I get: Error while processing SVF  "exception":"7719440"

Many other 3d models load normally in the forge viewer - this particular one throws the error above.  The dwfx file opens normally in Autodesk Design Review software

The viewer code is as follows:

Note: I've tried both this react version as well as just normal javascript and get the same error loading the DWFx. This code does function for loading some dwf and dwfx files.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import RestApi from "../RestApi";
import {Box} from "@mui/material";

export default function BLViewer(props) {

    const viewerRef = useRef(null);
    const viewerContainer = useRef();


    useEffect(() => {

    }, []);

    function onSelectionChanged(event) {
        if (event && event.nodeIdArray && event.nodeIdArray.length) {
            console.log(event);

            event.model.getProperties(event.nodeIdArray[0], function (resp) {
                const name = resp.name;
                const partNumber = name.split(":")[0];
                props.onSelect(partNumber);
            });
        }
    }

// Callback for successful model load
    function onLoadSuccess(model) {
        console.log('DWF file loaded successfully:', model);
        // Perform additional operations or access model data if needed
    }

// Callback for model load error
    function onLoadError(errorCode) {
        alert('Failed to load DWF file. Error code:', errorCode);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        new RestApi().get('/api/viewer/token').then(resp => {
            const token = resp.token;
            console.log('Token:', token);

            Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({
                //   accessToken: token,
                env: 'Local'
            }, async function () {
                // Create a viewer instance
                let view = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerContainer.current);

                view.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SHOW_EVENT, onSelectionChanged);
                view.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.HIDE_EVENT, onSelectionChanged);

                view.start();

                view.loadExtension('Autodesk.DWF').then(() => {
                    view.loadModel('/my-model.dwfx', {}, onLoadSuccess, onLoadError);
                });

                viewerRef.current = view;

            });
        }).catch(err => {
            alert('Error registering viewer');
        });
        return () => {
            if (viewerRef.current) {
                console.log('finish');
                viewerRef.current.finish();
                viewerRef.current = null;
            }
        };
    }, [props.path]);


    return (
        <Box style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>

            <div style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}} ref={viewerContainer}>

            </div>
        </Box>

    )
}
```

I've  tried re-exporting this DWF as DWF, DWFX, and toggling the various options in the Inventor DWF export screen (Full, Express, etc).

No combination of export options has produced a DWFx that the forge viewer will open

Comment: Could you please let us know if this error happens on every browser or it's specific to some?

Comment: I've encountered this issue on all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge, etc) across multiple operating systems (mac, ipad, windows 10/11 machines)

Comment: I'll also note, some of these dwfx files that fail to load, have been successfully processed into SVF2 format using the derivative api and can be viewed as that format without an issue after they are converted. If it helps, I'd be willing to share one of the models that fails.

Comment: Could you please retry with Viewer version "7.91.0"?